# Enable/Disable command buttons in CK Editor

Tags: ckeditor

I am new to CK Editor. I have a created a plugin that shows a button on UI. I want to disable and enable based on some condition.

So I am using the following code to enable

```
var command = editorInstance.getCommand('myButton')
command.enable()
```

and to disable

```
var command = editorInstance.getCommand('myButton')
command.disable()
```

functionality-wise this works fine but it shows button in disable mode always on UI(always greyed button)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a button with CSS by using the class names that CKEditor creates for toolbar buttons. Try this (tested with v4.5.11):

```
// hide
document.getElementsByClassName('cke_button__myButton')[0].style.display = 'none';
//show
document.getElementsByClassName('cke_button__myButton')[0].style.display = 'block';
```